# Cannot convert 'QJsonObject' to 'int' in return

Tags: c++, qt, qjson

So I have:

```cpp
QJsonArray nodeCollection;

nodeCollection.push_back(ListElements(program, "title", "lang"));
```

And my `ListElements` method declares `QJsonObject`, fills it with things that I need, and should return the object so that it can be pushed to `nodeCollection` array variable:

```cpp
ListElements (QDomElement root, QString tagname, QString attribute)
{

         auto nodeData = QJsonObject(
            {
            qMakePair(QString(itemElement.tagName()), QJsonValue(itemElement.text())),
            qMakePair(QString("lang"),QJsonValue(itemElement.attribute("lang"))),
            });

            return nodeData;  // <-- error
        }
    }
}
```

The error that I get is:

`error: cannot convert 'QJsonObject' to 'int' in return`

I'm obviously new to C++ and I've googled this issue with some success, but no concrete examples how to address this issue.

What am I doing wrong? How can I tell the method it should return `QJsonObject` instead of `int`?

Comment: Missing return type for method `ListElements` defaults to `int` return type.  You should also increase your compilers warning/error level detection.  If you already know this suggest you close the question as a typo.

Comment: In C/C++ you write the return type of a method in front of the name of the method. For example: `float getFloatNumber (char *str) { ..... }`

Comment: @SisterFister damn, that was it! So simple, I'm kicking myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add the return type to the beginning of the function prototype:

```
QJsonObject ListElements (QDomElement root, QString tagname, QString attribute)
```

If you don't specify a return type, the default assumed return type is `int`, that's why you got this error.

Answer (score 2):

If you write a function like this:

```
MyFunc(double, float) {
   ...
}
```

Then it is assumed to have a return type of `int` because no return type has been specified. If you want it to return something else you need to specify the return type:

```
QJsonObject MyFunc(double, float) {
   ...
}
```